# why does not it work that ng-show with expression?

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

I want to show something when some variate value is -1 with angular,like this:`<div ng-show="{{pid==-1}}">something</div>`,and it does not work.but it works like this :`<div ng-show="pid==-1">something</div>`.why does this happen?

Comment: Because `{{pid==-1}}` is not true or false value. `ng-show` work with true and false value.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use expression with {{}} in the ng-show, it does not evaluate

**invalid**

```
 <div ng-show="{{pid==-1}}">something</div>
```

**valid**

```
<div ng-show="pid==-1">something</div>
```